# Warnings in Dart Editor when creating a "Sample web application using the polymer library"

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I updated my version of the Dart Editor recently. At the same time, I upgraded Polymer to 0.12.0 in my main project.

I fixed the Polymer elements by adding the imports to the Polymer library as recommenced on the announcement of the breaking changes on the mailing list.

Even after fixing Polymer elements and the main HTML file to include platform.js and dart_support.js, I keep having warnings reported for every Polymer elements:

- couldn't find imported asset "lib/polymer.html" in package "polymer".
- Missing definition for `<polymer-element>`, please add the following HTML import at the top of this file: `<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">`.

I get the same warnings when creating the "Sample web application using the polymer library" (clickcounter).

I used the latest stable version of the Dart Editor and the dev channel version (1.6.0.dev_08_00). I even tried cleaning up the cache of pub libraries.

pubspec.yaml for the clickcounter project:

```
name: clickclick
description: A sample Polymer application
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.12.0 <0.13.0'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/clickclick.html
```

Any idea would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried it in bleeding edge and it worked without a problem. How did you try to fix your pub cache? `pub cache repair`?

Comment: I just wiped out the content of the folder `Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org`.

I've just tried `pub cache repair` with no luck.

Comment: Are you using Dart stable? I guess 1.6 will be released in a few days or try to download the dev-channel-release.

Comment: I was previously using one of the releases from the dev channel. I tried today with Dart stable 1.6 and I still get the issue when creating a new Polymer application from the template.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Mlhn9hw.png).

I tried to delete `%AppData%\Pub` and, even, the `.metadata` of the DartEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the folder "%AppData%\Pub" fixed this problem for me.